# Add function on form submit button (elementor)

Tags: javascript, redirect, elementor

I want to redirect to 2 pages on form submit.

- 1st page on the same tab.
- 2nd page on a new tab.

The first problem is the code itself... I'm not very familiar with javascript and etc...

The second problem is to implement it on an elementor form.

I've searched for some codes and found this:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

this.mybutton = document.getElementById("myidname");
this.mybutton.addEventListener("click", hello);

function hello (){
    window.open("https://www.amazon.com");
    window.location.replace(https://www.ebay.com)
    }

</script>
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: `https://www.ebay.com` needs to be in quotes. Other than that, I think this should work.

Comment: Would you know how to add this to a button? More specificly an Elementor Form Submit button ...

Comment: I'm not familiiar with Elementor.